# Generate Bitcoin address with privatekey

Tags: bitcoind

I am able to create new bitcoin address using jsonrpc by accessing the bitcoind client, where I am able to get only the account name and address but I could not get private or public key.  Is there anyother approach to create new bitcoin address with private and public key.

Comment: I can't tell you how to get the keys in the bitcoind client, but an address is ALWAYS generated by the public key and the public key is ALWAYS generated by the private key. Maybe that information helps you.